# PHP mb_substr() not working correctly?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, multibyte, mbstring

This code

`print mb_substr('éxxx', 0, 1);`

prints an empty space :(

It is supposed to print the first character, `é`. This seems to work however:

`print mb_substr('éxxx', 0, 2);`

But it's not right, because (0, 2) means 2 characters...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try passing the encoding parameter to mb_substr, as such:

```
print mb_substr('éxxx', 0, 1, 'utf-8');
```

The encoding is never detected automatically.

Comment: The encoding is *never* detected automatically, it just always *defaults* to something.

Comment: Could it be a better idea if you use [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to *actually* try to detect the encoding?

Comment: @AlvinWong No. *Know* what encoding you're working with, there's no other way.

Comment: @Alvin Wong, that would be more correct, yes, but I could also say that using anything but utf-8 can be considered adventurous and marginal :)

Comment: @deceze, wasn't sure, but thanks for the clarification, I updated the answer.

Comment: tx that works. Can mb_substr work like `substr($string, 1)` without giving it the mb_strlen() argument ?

Comment: @Alex, that I think is another question, but my guess would be that yes - because the parameter is optional as it is in substr.

Comment: yes, but that UTF-8 thing has to go after that argument. Anyway nvm, I`ll just use mb_strlen ..

Comment: OK, then how about [`mb_internal_encoding`](http://hk1.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) instead of passing `"utf-8"` to all `mb_*` functions? Just like Álvaro G. Vicario has pointed out

Comment: @AlvinWong is right, it's better to look to mb_internal_encoding if this is not only function usage and you are planning to use a lot of mb_* functions through out your code.

Answer (score 13):

In practice I've found that, in some systems, multi-byte functions default to ISO-8859-1 for internal encoding. That effectively ruins their ability to handle multi-byte text.

Setting a good default will probably fix this and some other issues:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```