# Corrupted data using UTF-8 and mb_substr

Tags: php, utf-8, mbstring

I'm get data from MySQL db, varchar(255) utf8_general_ci field and try to write the text to a PDF with PHP. I need to determine the string length in the PDF to limit the output of the text in a table. But I noticed that the output of `mb_substr`/`substr` is really strange.

For example:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$_tmpStr = $vfrow['title'];
$_tmpStrLen = mb_strlen($vfrow['title']);
for($i=$_tmpStrLen; $i >= 0; $i--){
     file_put_contents('cutoffattributes.txt',$vfrow['field']." ".$_tmpStr."\n",FILE_APPEND);
     file_put_contents('cutoffattributes.txt',$vfrow['field']." ".mb_substr($_tmpStr, 0, $i)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
}
```

outputs this:

[image: screen shot from npp]

[npp file link](http://filebin.ca/1zE2Mc2zdXbA/cutoffatributes2.txt)

Database:

[image]
[image]

My question is where does the extra character come from?

Comment: You're not providing an encoding to mb_substr; are you sure it's getting the right encoding? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953248/php-mb-substr-not-working-correctly), as well.

Comment: You use mb_strlen()/mb_substr() instead of strlen()/substr() because that could slice a multibyte-character in the middle, which is correct. What even mb_strlen()/mb_substr() can do is to slice a composite sequence in the middle, like the "n" and the accent on top. You might get away transcoding the content to a non-composite form, which exists for some accented letters.

Comment: Can You show us output of `bin2hex ($_tmpStr)`, after the variable is set?

Comment: @Michas bin2hex: 526f7a6d696172206369c499636961206b617761c5826b69207069657277737a792073746f706965c584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to ensure you're actually getting the data from the database in UTF-8 encoding by setting your connection encoding appropriately. This depends on your database adapter, see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for details.
2. You need to tell your `mb_` functions that the data is in UTF-8 so they can treat it correctly. Either set this globally for all functions using [`mb_internal_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_internal_encoding), or pass the `$encoding` parameter to your function when you call it:

   ```
   mb_substr($_tmpStr, 0, $i, 'UTF-8')
   ```

Comment: I did use mb_internal_encoding but setting the encoding parameter of mb_substr to UTF-8 did work!

Answer (score 1):

The extra character is first part of two byte UTF-8 sequence. You may have problems with internal encoding of Multibyte String Functions. Your code treats text as fixed, 1-byte encoding. The **ń** in UTF-8, hex C5 84, is treated as **Ĺ„** in CP-1250 and **Ĺ<sub>[IND]</sub>** in ISO-8859-2, two characters.

Try to execute this one on the top of script:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing out but i did set mb_internal_encoding to utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Aside from table and field being set to UTF-8 you need to  set [mysqli_set_charset('UTF-8')](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) to UTF-8 also (if you are using mysqli).

Also did you try?

```
$_tmpStr = utf8_encode( $vfrow['title'] );
```

Comment: I already did this thats why i dont undestand this behavior... SET NAMES utf8 & SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'

Comment: would you improve your question with actual table structure and few data from it?